# Removing exponent from equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, numerical-methods, logarithms, roots

I'm trying to solve the following equation numerically:

[image]

This is problematic, because the term $ t^{\beta_i}_{j} $ becomes extremely large ($> 10000^{300}$), and unrepresentable with typical number representations. Perhaps someone with better algebra chops than me can see a way to apply logarithms or other tricks, and get rid of that exponent?

This can be assumed: $t_j > 0$ , $\beta_{i} > 0$, $(n-r) > 0$ and $0 \leq Pr\{.\} \leq 1$